Make ‘jump-to-register’ reuse an existing window
For example, if I save the current position in a register from the left window here, and then call jump-to-register from the right window,

Emacs switches the right window to the buffer where I saved the position:

Can I make it select the left window instead? So that after calling jump-to-register I get


I don't know if it's the best thing to do but this works:
(defun reusing-window-if-possible (orig-fn &rest args)
  "When ORIG-FN switches to another buffer, select a window that is already
displaying that buffer if there is one."
  (let ((switch-to-buffer-obey-display-actions t)
        (display-buffer-overriding-action '((display-buffer-reuse-window))))
    (apply orig-fn args)))

(advice-add 'jump-to-register :around #'reusing-window-if-possible)

